# Gulp.js watch is not working in VS 2019 when saving

Tags: visual-studio-2019, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my gulp.js file to allow for the user to hit save and it update my .css file from the .sass file change?

If I manually hit Run under my Task it will work

Can anyone see any issues?

```
/// <binding AfterBuild='compile' ProjectOpened='default' />
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

// Requires the gulp-sass plugin
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task("sass", function (done) {
    return gulp.src('Content/styles/**/*.scss', '!Content/styles/vendor')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Content/styles/'));
});

function watch() {
    gulp.watch('Content/styles/**/*.scss', gulp.series("sass"));
}

gulp.task("compile", gulp.series("sass"));

gulp.task('default', watch);
```